# Why Logical Read reduce the performance - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

**Logical Reads** - Reading the data from the data cache

**Physical Reads** - Reading the data from Disk

Usually, we are using the caches for better performance, it will reduce the time to access the data from the disk.

But in SQL, why reducing the logical reads improve performance?
If data cache affects the performance, then why we need that data cache in middle?

I'm new to SQL tuning, please clarify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A logical read is a request to read a block.  It may be served from cache or it may be served from disk.  If it is served from disk, it is also a physical read.  All physical reads are also logical reads.

What SQL Server (or any database) calls a physical read may or may not actually require going to spinning disk.  The operating system might have a cache, the SAN array might have a cache, etc.  A physical read from SQL Server simply means that SQL Server didn't have the block in cache.

Normally, when we're tuning a query, we focus on logical reads because that is a relatively stable value and a query that does less logical I/O will generally be faster than one that does more logical I/O.  When we're tuning a query or when we're running it from our application, what fraction of our logical reads are actually physical reads is somewhat up to chance.  If you're working on tuning a query, it is very likely that the data you're relying on is quickly going to get cached so your physical I/O will go down if you just keep running the query.  When the query runs in production, you might get lucky and find that most of the blocks are in cache and there is very little I/O or you might get unlucky and find that very few of the blocks are in cache.  If you focus on physical I/O when you're tuning, you'll be chasing a constantly moving target.  And since SQL Server can't differentiate between a physical read that was actually served from the operating system cache or a physical read that was served from the SAN cache or a physical read that was served from a SSD in the SAN or a physical read that was served by going to actual physical spinning disk, you're mixing a bunch of different things with very different performance profiles together.  If you run the query 100 times, you'll get roughly the same number of logical I/Os every time.  You'll get wildly different numbers of physical I/Os and those physical I/Os are likely to have wildly different performance characteristics because some will be hitting physical disk and some will just be hitting the operating system cache.

As a **very** rough first approximation for most OLTP systems, the odds that a block you want is in cache is going to be roughly constant (most queries are reading relatively recent rows in most tables that are mostly cached).  If your system keeps 95% of the blocks that you're reading in cache, you can reasonably guess that if you have a query that does 1000 logical I/O's per execution, on average it's going to do 50 physical I/O's per execution.  Sometimes you'll get lucky and it'll do 0 physical I/Os, sometimes you'll get luck and it'll do 250 physical I/Os but on average you'll get 50.  If you reduce the logical I/O, you'll probably reduce the physical I/O by the same fraction.

Of course, this is a **very** rough approximation.  If you've got a poorly performing query that does a table scan of a multi-million row table, the odds that all the 10 year old rows are cached is a lot lower than the odds that the recent blocks that you actually mostly want to read are cached.  If you get rid of the full-scan's logical I/O, you'll probably get a much larger percentage-wise reduction in physical I/O because you're focusing the query on the recent blocks that SQL Server is really good at caching.

And, of course, sometimes we're focused on things other than logical I/O.  Sometimes our systems are CPU-bound not I/O-bound and we want to focus on how much CPU a query is using.  Sometimes our systems are under memory pressure and we want to tune how much memory a query uses.  But normally database systems are I/O bound and starting with a focus on logical I/O is normally reasonable when we tune a query.

Comment: @lrf92 - Not sure what sites you're looking at but the SQL Server documentation is pretty clear on this point and will obviously be rather authoritative https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/reading-pages?view=sql-server-ver15